# Which date is lifecycle checking?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've set my Lifecycle like below. The files are deleted. But I don't understand which date it is comparing?

Because the MODIFIED date has already over 1 day. But my files still haven't been deleted

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "1daytest",
            "type": "Lifecycle",
            "definition": {
                "actions": {
                    "baseBlob": {
                        "delete": {
                            "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                "filters": {
                    "blobTypes": [
                        "blockBlob"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you clarify something? you say the files deleted at first, but then you say "But my files still haven't been deleted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For baseblob(not snapshot): Base blobs use the **last modified time** to track age. More details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts#rule-actions).

And also note that: The platform runs the lifecycle policy once a day. Once you configure a policy, it can take up to **24 hours** for some actions to run for the first time.

Comment: once a day. What time is it?

Comment: @Jeff_hu, I didn't find the specification in ms doc, but it did delete the blobs as per the rule definition as per my test.